# Why is moving data out of the reference allowed in this situation?

Tags: rust

In chapter [4.5 Ownership Recap](https://rust-book.cs.brown.edu/ch04-05-ownership-recap.html) of The Rust Programming Language book, the author argues that moving data out of the reference is not allowed and provides the following code snippet:

```
fn main() {
    let mut s = String::from("Hello");
    let s_ref = &s;
    let s2 = *s_ref;
    println!("{s}");
}
```

The line `let s2 = *s_ref;` is not allowed, since own permission is expected, but the path does not have the permission. This code does not compile.

Further on in the same section, the following code snippet is presented:

```
fn main() {
    let v = vec![1, 2, 3];
    let v_ref: &Vec<i32> = &v;
    let v2 = *v_ref;
    drop(v2);
    drop(v);
}
```

Here, the author says that line `let v2 = *v_ref;` is completely fine. However, this code still does not compile since there's a double-free: `v2` and `v` reference the same data in the heap, so the memory cannot be freed twice using `drop()`. I get that, but what I don't get is why `let v2 = *v_ref;` is accepted here and not in the previous code snippet.

Comment: *"but what I don't get is why let v2 = *v_ref; is accepted here and not in the previous code snippet"*, … you just told us it doesn't compile, what makes you think this is accepted? It's not!

Comment: @cafce25 the reason why the second snippet does not compile is because of the double `drop()` not because of `let v2 = *v_ref;`.

Comment: Go ahead and remove either or both `drop` from that snippet and try to compile!

Comment: @cafce25 you're right. It does not compile. The diagram below the snippet suggests that it does. Very confusing. Thank you for your comments.

Comment: Not quite, the diagram is a hypothetical, if it *were* to compile, it would lead to a double free, but it doesn't.